# How to access Many-to-Many field data from a different model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Work_Music(MPTTModel, Work):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)   
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    tonality = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class WorkCast(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work'), related_name='workcast', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Cast, verbose_name=_('cast'), related_name='workcast', blank=True)
    order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Cast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

In view.py, I send the following in template context:

```
work = Work_Music.objects.get(work=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

How do I access WorkCast via the Work_Music object?

How do I display in the template,

```
 Cast #1, Cast #2, Cast #3, Cast #4
```

How to I grab all of the cast members? Is it?

```
work.workcast.cast.all()
```

doesn't yield any output.

How do I display it as a list with commas in between?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the reverse model reference `_set` in django. You can find more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships). In your case you would do something like,

```
work_music = WorkMusic.object.get(pk=1)
work_music.workcast_set.all() # would get you all workcast related to that work music object
```

Hope this helps!